# I want to access a file from a folder using web config

Tags: c#, web-config

I want to select a file like .txt or .docs or .nacha from a specified folder, and i want the code to write in web.config file of my project.

Comment: I don't think you want that. Read up on what web.config is about.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the web.config file programmatially

refer

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/update-web-config-programmatically